# Calling rest api secured with Bearer token authentication in Apache Camel route

Tags: java, authentication, apache-camel, spring-camel

I need to call a Rest API from my Apache Camel route. The Rest API is secured with a token that can be obtained on andother API.

My demo route looks like following:

```
    from("direct:iot")
        .id("iot")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
        .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
        .setBody(simple(STR."username=\{USERNAME}&password=\{PASSWORD}&grant_type=password&client_id=iot-api-client&client_secret=\{CLIENT_SECRET}"))
        .to(TOKEN_URL)
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson)
        .process(e -> {
            Map body = e.getIn().getBody(Map.class);
            e.getIn().setHeader("Authorization",
                STR."Bearer \{body.get("access_token")}");
        })
        .removeHeader("*")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
        .to(STR."\{BASE_URL}\{RESOURCE_URI}")
        .log("${body}");
```

It works but it seems quite complicatied to me (I should also add some error handling, token caching etc.). I wonder if it can be simplified somehow.

In the [APACHE CAMEL 4.2 WHAT'S NEW](https://camel.apache.org/blog/2023/11/camel42-whatsnew/) they write:

> "The camel-http component now supports OAuth 2.0 client
> authentication."

Unfortunately I was not able to find any details.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this unit test `HttpOAuth2AuthenticationTest` and there is also a little bit docs as there are new oauth options on the http component.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The test is realy selfexplanatory. I have also foud the bit of documentation on http component. Unfortunately it clearly says "Camel only provide support for OAuth2 client credentials flow". My REST API uses Password grant type OAuth2 authentication. So I am out of luck :-(